# No entiendo cuál es el origen del error "list index out of range"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy realizando una serie de ejercicios muy simples que encontré para practicar, y resulta que en uno de ellos se me pide que cree una función que sea capaz de tomar todos los números de una lista y sumarlos, algo así como una secuencia Fibonacci. El problema está en que cuando corro el programa me salta "list index out of range". Ya detecté el punto exacto que hace estallar mi código, este es el momento en el que la variable "index" pasa a recorrer la lista dentro del elemento `for`, pero no entiendo el porque ocurre esto ni que problema tiene la variable "index" al usarse para recorrer la lista.

Aquí les dejo el código.

```
print("Suma y multiplicacion de listas: ")

numeros = input("Indique la serie de numeros que decea sumar y multiplicar 
sin espacios ni comas de por medio: ")

lista = []

for i in numeros:
    lista.append(i)

def sum(lista):

    var1 = int(lista[0])
    var2 = int(lista[1])
    var3 = var1 + var2

    num = len(lista[:]) + 1 

    index = 2

    for j in range(0, num):
        var1 = var3
        var2 = int(lista[index])
        var3 = var1 + var2

        index += 1


    return var3

print(sum(lista))
```

Y este es el error que me aparece:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ejercicios2.py", line 98, in <module>
    print(sum(lista))
  File "ejercicios2.py", line 90, in sum
    var2 = int(lista[index])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Muchas gracias de antemano y espero poder aprender de sus respuestas.

Comment: El error es claro, la variable `index` inicia en 2: `index = 2`, asumiendo que lista tiene n elementos entonces `num = n + 1` por lo que j toma valores de 0 hasta n, y en cada iteración de j la variable index se incrementa en 1 por lo que index varia desde 2 hasta n+1, asi que lista[n] y lista[n+1] debe lanzar esa excepcion

Answer (score 0):

Un error del tipo “list index out of range” significa que intentas acceder a un elemento en una posición mayor que el tamaño del `array`, por ejemplo si intentas extraer el elemento de la posición 3 de un `array` de dos elementos, es decir, la posición 3 no existe.

¿Por qué se produce ese error en tu código?

En este fragmento de código:

```
for j in range(0, num):
        var1 = var3
        var2 = int(lista[index])
        var3 = var1 + var2
```

j va tomando los valores 0, 1, 2 ... hasta num.
index inicializado a 2, tomará los valores 2 , 3 , 4 ... asi hasta 2+num.
Si num indica el numero de elementos , el elemento en la osicion 2+num no existirá, puesto que es mayor que num.

Tu error es, inicialiazar mal el index, puesto que deberías inicializarlo a 0 puesto que es el primer elemento.

Otro error, realizar un bucle for controlado por num, pero en cambio usar e incrementar index, en vez de j. O haber utilizado index en vez de j.

Solución: Inicializar bien la variable e usar sólo un índice, o J o index.
Quedaría de la siguiente forma :

```
for j in range(0, num):
        var1 = var3
        var2 = int(lista[j])
        var3 = var1 + var2
```

o:

```
for index in range(0, num):
        var1 = var3
        var2 = int(lista[index])
        var3 = var1 + var2

        index += 1
```

Comment: o mejor `for e in lista:` `...` `var2 = int(e)`. Por otro lado en tu último código `index += 1` es innecesario

Comment: Cierto @eyllanesc , puedes editar la respuesta y añadir las correcciones que veas.

Comment: Solo los señalare, si lo consideras relevante entonces añadelo tú.

Comment: @eyllanesc lo son para que el ejemplo le valga, al menos el ultimo que mencionas. Y la simplificación de código es bienvenida.

Comment: Puedes añadirlo como otra opción